# Contradiction in book related to variable scope in Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, stored-procedures

I was reading the 70-461 TSQL training book and the part about stored procedures said this:

> Variables declared in Proc1 and Proc1's parameters are not visible to any of the procedures called by Proc1

But in the same book was this example code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sales.ListCustomerByAddress
(@address AS NVARCHAR(60))
AS
DECLARE @SQLString AS NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @SQLString = '
SELECT companyname, contactname
FROM Sales.Customers WHERE address = @address';

EXECUTE sp_executesql
         @statement = @SQLString,
         @params = N'@address NVARCHAR(60)',
         @address = @address;
RETURN;  
GO
```

My understanding of the quoted statement is that the `@SQLString` variable and `@address` parameter cannot be visible to and referenced by the `sp_executesql` procedure? A variable is an object that holds a value so If it is not there or cannot be seen (for instance in `@statement =` ) how can the value be used or passed

Can someone help reconcile this contradiction?

Comment: Why is this contradicting?

Comment: The sp_executesql proc being called in the sales.ListCustomerByAddress proc can see the @sqlstring that was declared in the latter

Comment: No it doesn't. The value of `@SQLString` is passed to the parameter `@statement` of the sp_executesql.

Comment: But in the statement i quoted above, it says the `@SQLString` and `@address` shouldn't be visible to the sp_executesql proc  @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: @SQLString and @address are not visible and cannot be modifed by sp_executesql. Their values though are passed to the procedure. All procedures have parameters. If I call procedure `alpha()` with parameters `b` and `c`: `execute alpha(b=13, c='Peter')`, I expect that the values `13` and `'Peter'` to be indeed available inside the procedure. If I do `bbb=13; ccc='Peter'; execute alpha(b=bbb, c=ccc)`, I expect the same. The values 13 and Peter are still available inside the procedure but variables `bbb` and `ccc` are not visible.

Comment: I appreciate that detailed reply but if something is not visible how can it be referenced? Also, you clearly know more than I do but a variable is an object that holds a value. If it is not there or cannot be seen (in `@statement = `) how can the value be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no contradiction in that documentation. The confusion here seems to be that there is an implied assumption regarding the reader's expectations of how variable scope works. In many other languages, variables declared in an outer scope are visible to subroutines / functions. For example (and this is *not* how it works in T-SQL; I am just illustrating how variable scope often works):

```
int OuterVariable = 5;

function int Sub1 (int Param1)
{
  int InnerVariable = 10;

  return InnerVariable + OuterVariable + Param1;
}

int Result = Sub1(3);
```

Since variables declared in an outer scope are often visible to inner scopes (i.e. global), the code above wouldn't error when calling `Sub1` stating that `OuterVariable` hasn't been declared. Instead, the subroutine would have access to the value of `OuterVariable` (and in some languages, it might even be able to overwrite that value). Hence, the value of `Result` at the end would be **18**.

So, when the book states:

> "Variables declared in Proc1 and Proc1's parameters are not visible to any of the procedures called by Proc1"

they are saying that T-SQL does not work like that. They are not saying that variables in Proc1 *cannot* be passed into a sub-Proc call; they are saying that if you want those values in the sub-Proc call, then you *must* pass them in explicitly via input parameters. Essentially, "visible" means "available without explicitly passing in via input parameters".

Maybe this will help illustrate:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InnerProc(@InnerInputParam INT, @InnerName NVARCHAR(30))
AS
SELECT @InnerInputParam AS [InnerParam], @InnerName AS [InnerName];

-- SELECT @OuterName; -- commented out as this is a parse error
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.OuterProc(@OuterInputParam INT)
AS
DECLARE @OuterName NVARCHAR(30) = N'Mr. Outer Scope';

EXEC dbo.InnerProc
        @InnerInputParam = @OuterInputParam,
        @InnerName = @OuterName;
GO
```

Executing `EXEC dbo.OuterProc 5;` or `EXEC dbo.OuterProc @OuterInputParam = 5;` (same thing) will return:

```
InnerParam     InnerName
5              Mr. Outer Scope
```

Those values are "known" by dbo.InnerProc because they were passed in. And they were passed in because they were not "visible" to dbo.InnerProc, even though they existed in the outer / parent scope of dbo.OuterProc during execution. But neither `@OuterInputParam` nor `@OuterName` can be referenced in dbo.InnerProc because inner / child scopes have no knowledge of outer / parent scopes, at least not for variables (including Table Variables) and parameters.

Finally, to relate all of this back to the initial example in the book, this is why I do my best to change variable names when using `sp_executesql`: to make the code more readable. Changing one variable name might make it quite a bit clearer:

```sql
SET @SQLString = '
SELECT companyname, contactname
FROM Sales.Customers WHERE address = @InnerAddress';

EXECUTE sp_executesql
         @statement = @SQLString,
         @params = N'@address NVARCHAR(60)',
         @InnerAddress = @address;
```

Comment: Beautifully put. In other words, the nested scope of the sub proc cannot gain access to the `@SQLString` and `@address` stated in the higher scope of the nesting proc without stating said variables/parameters clearly again as inputs. Thank you.